# Automatic updating data values to multiple users ASP .NET 4 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

working on a small app for a few people i work with.

I have 5 users that will access a web based ASP .NET app using C# this app will have counter control taht can be incremented for each agent (the counter will reset at the end of each day) what would be the best way to enusre this control will be updated across all users screens if one user increments an agents counter ?

Thank you in advanced for any assistance !

Comment: A simple method would be to use polling AJAX - say with jQuery or whatnot. Of course you'll still need to correctly handle synchronization issues which may occur (e.g. should it increment twice or warn if two users increment the counter while they see it as the same?) and provide the appropriate counter store (e.g. database). While an UpdatePanel would also work, it does incur *much* more overhead than a simple AJAX/PageMethod call. See [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider storing the counter in a database and use some AJAX calls to refresh the counter automatically on your website. If you store the counter in a table with two columns 'date' and 'counter', you can keep a nice history of your visitor counts and plot these somewhere else on your site when you have some days of history.

Comment: i hadnt thought about using AJAX thanks for the idea ! the graphing option is great too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) a library for Asp.Net that makes really easy to write real-time web applications, it comes with a javascript client so it helps a lot in the client side.

So you could be pooling the database to see if there was an increment in agents counter, but I think that a better solution is to use Domain Events in the server side, so whenever there is an increment in the an agent counter, a domain event will be fired and spread the change through the clients using SignalR.